# Treat segment of data as 16-bit integer in C

Tags: c, integer, checksum, 16-bit

I'm trying to compute the checksum of a segment of data. As the Internet checksum algorithm says, it begins by treating the segment as a sequence of 16-bit integers. My question is, how can I separate data of the type char *buff into 16-bit integers so I can then computer the sum?

Comment: `As the algorithm says` : what algorithm are you taling about, the crc function ?

Comment: The one for computing internet checksum

Comment: You don't need to "separate", you just need to "interpret". Which means use a `uint16_t` pointer.

Comment: what do you mean by this?